Emacs: elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer is not using Python virtualenv
I am using GNU Emacs 29.3 on Windows 11 and have configured Elpy manually. I am a beginner in Elpy. It seems to be working as expected. I can see the auto-completion and documentation hints.
However, when I press C-c C-c in my Python code (to invoke elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer as mentioned at https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#command-elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer), it is not able to recognize the paramiko module installed in the virtual environment created by Elpy at ~/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default. I have installed paramiko inside the above environment using pip.
In the below screenshot I get the ModuleNotfoundError for the paramiko module. Somehow it is using the system Python and not the Elpy's virtual environment.
But the documentation is showing all necessary info (in the below screenshot). Is there another command I should use to execute the script in the virtual env?

The workaround I am using is M-x shell -> activate venv manually through activate.bat -> run the script.
NOTE: Since my organization prevents downloading packages from Elpa/Melpa, I have added the following in my init.el (putting only relavent portions). Note that I cloned all relevant repositories in D:\emacs_packages and used them manually.
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/company-mode")
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/pyvenv")
(require 'pyvenv)

;; Support for ipython
(when (executable-find "ipython")
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"))

;; emacs-deferred -- needed by emacs-epc
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-deferred")
(require 'deferred)
(require 'concurrent)

;; emacs-ctable -- needed by emacs-epc
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-ctable")
(require 'ctable)

;; emacs-epc - needed for Jedi.el
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-epc")
(require 'epc)

;; popup-el -- needed for auto-complete
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/popup-el")
(require 'popup)

;; auto-complete -- needed for jedi
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/auto-complete")
(require 'auto-complete)
;; (ac-config-default) - giving error
(auto-complete-mode)

;; python-environment -- needed for jedi
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-python-environment")
(require 'python-environment)

;; Jedi.el for Python auto-completion
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-jedi")
(require 'jedi)
(autoload 'jedi:setup "jedi" nil t)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional

;; highlight-indentation - needed for elpy
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs")
(require 'highlight-indentation)

;; yasnippet - needed for elpy
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; s.el - needed for elpy
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/s.el")
(require 's)

;; elpy - Python IDE
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/elpy")
(load "elpy")
(load "elpy-rpc")
(load "elpy-shell")
(load "elpy-profile")
(load "elpy-refactor")
(load "elpy-django")
(elpy-enable)  
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi") 

;; For folding code in Elpy
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'hs-minor-mode)



Does running M-x elpy-config show you any errors or misconfiguration?

As per suggestion from @bikemule,
Running M-x elpy-config showed me the below. Clearly the Python virtual environment was not active.
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 29.3
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python 3.8.10 (c:/Users/amit_tendulkar/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (c:/Users/amit_tendulkar/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: c:/WINDOWS/py.exe 3.8.10 (c:/WINDOWS/py.exe)
 Jedi.............: 0.19.1
 Autopep8.........: 2.3.1
 Yapf.............: 0.40.2
 Black............: 24.4.2
Syntax checker....: Not found (flake8)

Warnings

You have not activated a virtual env. It is not mandatory but often a
good idea to work inside a virtual env. You can use `M-x
pyvenv-activate` or `M-x pyvenv-workon` to activate one.

The configured syntax checker (flake8) could not be found. Elpy uses
this program to provide syntax checks of your code. You can either
install it, or select another one using `elpy-syntax-check-command`.

[Install flake8]
...

So, I did M-x pyvenv-activate and provided the virtual env path to activate it (modline showed that the environment is now active).
When I did C-c C-c again, this time the script evaluation worked.
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
... ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()

>>> 

